# Python Requests Module Not Getting Latest Data from Web Server

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

In the code snippet below, you can see that I am trying to scrape some data from the NCAA Men's Basketball website.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.ncaa.com/scoreboard/basketball-men/d1/"

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text

print(html)
print(response.headers)
print("\n\n")
print(response.request.headers)
```

The website has a listing of games and their scores. I figured out how to pull all the data I need using Python Requests for the HTTP request and then BeautifulSoup for extracting data from the HTML. [The full scraper is here if you'd like to take a look.](https://repl.it/@joekreydt/MadnessTheBot07)

**The problem:** When Requests gets the response from the NCAA website, the data is much older (sometimes up to 30 or 40 minutes, at least) than the data on the actual website.

I've been Googling this for hours. After reading through the [Python Requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), I believe I have discovered that the NCAA web server is sending outdated data. But I don't understand why it would send my program outdated data when it sends Google Chrome (or whatever web browser) the correct data.

The reason I believe the server is sending outdated data is that when I print the response headers, one of the items is *'Last-Modified': 'Sat, 26 Jan 2019 17:49:13 GMT'* while another is *'Date': 'Sat, 26 Jan 2019 18:20:29 GMT'*, so it looks like the server gets the request at the right time, but provides data that hasn't been modified in a while.

**My question:** Do you know of any reason why this would happen? Is there something I need to add in my HTTP request that would get the server to send me data consistent with what is sends web browsers?

P.S. I am so sorry for the long question. I tried to keep it concise, yet still explain things clearly.

Comment: Have you tried adding headers to your request?

Comment: Adding the header did not seem to work. It still does not pull the latest data. However, I am working on implementing your JSON solution as that does seem to resolve the issue. I just need to read up on parsing JSON with Python or BeautifulSoup now. Thank you!

Comment: You wouldn't need BeautifulSoup to parse. Use the implementation I have below to get the json response. It's just a matter of how you want to flatten out the json format. Check my solution out below. I added an extra line that could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

before your `requests.get()`, try adding a header:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.ncaa.com/scoreboard/basketball-men/d1/"

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}   


response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
html = response.text
```

My other suggestion would be to use:

```
url = 'https://data.ncaa.com/casablanca/scoreboard/basketball-men/d1/2019/01/26/scoreboard.json'
```

and use json package to read it. Everything is live and right there for you in a nice JSON format

**Code**

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://data.ncaa.com/casablanca/scoreboard/basketball-men/d1/2019/01/26/scoreboard.json'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}    

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

jsonStr = response.text

jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

I checked, and the JSON object does return live scores/data. And all you need to do is change the date in the URL `2019/01/26` to get previous dates finished data for games.

---

**EDIT - ADDITIONAL**

This could help you pull out the data. Notice how I changed it to today's date to get the current data. It puts it in a nice dataframe for you:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json
import requests

url = 'https://data.ncaa.com/casablanca/scoreboard/basketball-men/d1/2019/01/27/scoreboard.json'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}    

# Thanks to InfectedDrake wisdom, the following 3 lines that I previously had can be replaced by a single line. See below
#response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
#jsonStr = response.text
#jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)

jsonObj = requests.get(url, headers = headers).json()

result = json_normalize(jsonObj['games'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Note: `requests` has [built-in json support](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).

Comment: @InfectedDrake does it really!? Had no idea. Thanks. I’ll have to look at that then as I’ve always just done it this way.

Comment: @chitown88 will this have the march madness games as well? And is there a json feed for the schedule of the games?

Comment: @FamicTech  It does look like it will have the tournament scores. Ie. if you go back and look one of last years tourny date `https://data.ncaa.com/casablanca/scoreboard/basketball-men/d1/2018/03/25/scoreboard.json` you'll see `"bracketRound": "Elite Eight&#174;"`. As far as the schedule, I would assume that will display aswell as it currently does allow you to jump ahead and look at upcoming games. There is also the `https://data.ncaa.com/casablanca/carmen/brackets/championships/basketball-men/d1/2019/data.json` to get it, but obviously blank until the seeding would be announced.

Comment: @chitown88 I just realized that the json file you have provided does not provide the box scores for the games. It just has straight up scores for the away and home teams? Last year I used the following: http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/scoreboard/basketball-men/d1/2017/01/31/scoreboard.html which included everything

Comment: @FamicTechyou are correct, it's only the scores. For boxscores, I'd have to see where that is stored. But I'm going to assume you could probably just use your endpoint from last year and just update it with the date and year you want

Comment: @chitown88 the endpoint i used last year does not seem to be 'in service' anymore :(

Comment: @FamicTech, ah bummer. You're right. I'm going to look now and see what they did for this season.

Comment: @FamicTech ok, figured it out. Sort of annoying, but it looks like you need to get the scheduled games first, and then feed the team names seo <awayTeam-homeTeam> into the request url: 
 'https://data.ncaa.com/game/basketball-men/d1/{date}'  with date in the form of `YY/M/d`. Shoot me an email and I'll email the code to you. It's just a general idea, but you can mess around and play with it. jason.schvach@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the user-agent in the request header to make it the same as your Google Chrome user-agent by adding this to your headers:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Add your google chrome user-agent here'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I like your GitHub profile btw... "while (1) { code; skate; }"

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the above answers, the thing you need to do is to set a legitimate user-agent. Therefore add headers to emulate a browser:

```
# This is a standard user-agent of Chrome browser running on Windows 10 
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' }
```

Additionally, you can add another set of headers to pretend (more) like a legitimate browser. Add some more headers like this:

```
headers = { 
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36', 
'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 
'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 
'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip', 
'DNT' : '1', # Do Not Track Request Header 
'Connection' : 'close' }
```